# Show that in an arbitrage-free and non-redundant market a certain set is compact

Tags: arbitrage, mathematics, no-arbitrage-theory, theory

Some notation: We consider a financial market with $d+1$ assets, the $0$-th asset is considered the risk-free asset, the others are the risky ones. The vector $\overline \pi \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$ denotes the pricing vectors, and the random vector $\overline S = (S^0,S^1,\ldots, S^d)$ denotes the vector of the random variables corresponding to the assets. Further we have $\pi^0 = 1, S^0 \equiv 1 + r$, as these are risk-free.

Here a portfolio $\overline \xi \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$ is called an *arbitrage opportunity* if $\overline \xi \cdot \overline \pi \le 0$ but $\overline \xi \cdot \overline S \ge 0$ P-a.s. and $P(\overline \xi \cdot \overline S > 0) > 0$. And the market model is called *non-redundant* if
$$
 \overline \xi \cdot \overline S = 0 ~\mbox{P-a.s.} \Rightarrow \overline \xi = 0
$$
i.e. non of the assets $S^i$ could be synthezied by investing in the others.

> Show that in a non-redundant and arbitrage-free market model the set
>   $$
>  \{ \overline \xi \in \mathbb R^{d+1} : | \overline \pi \cdot \overline \xi = w \mbox{ and } \overline \xi \cdot \overline S \ge 0 ~ \mbox{P-a.s.} \}
> $$
>   is compact for any $w > 0$.

First, as this is a subset of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^{d+1}$, compactness is equivalent with bounded and closed. But already showing boundedness gives me a hard time, I do not see where to start?

Also, I guess a non-redundant market model also implies that it is arbitrage-free, so the presupposition of just arbitrage-free'ness should be enough.

Comment: Is there a reference book, or some other background, for this question?

Comment: Is this continuous or discrete? If it is discrete, then how many states you can have?

Comment: It is an exercise form H. Föllmer, Stochastic Finance, 3rd edition, 1. Chapter. The number of assets is finite (and thereby discrete, see my preliminary remarks, their number is $d$), but everything else is continuous, as for example the measure space on which the $S^i$ are defined could be arbitrary, and of course the values the $S^i$ could attain are not restricted too, does this answer your question?

Comment: I think if we assume the set is compact, then we have no arbitrage. I guess you could try to find a proof for that in some text and see if the converse is proved in the same text. [?](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=b4nbBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22compact%22+%22separating+hyperplane%22+%22arbitrage%22&source=bl&ots=sVeixVBdAH&sig=PIPdqgJ994N3EVcL3xqmbB_aI0I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI3-6I-ODJAhWoe6YKHZNCAJYQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22compact%22%20%22separating%20hyperplane%22%20%22arbitrage%22&f=false) or [?](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~shumway/courses.dir/ba855.dir/noarb.PDF)

Comment: Just found this question now and I would be interested to know how boundedness of the set can be proven? How can I involve the ideas of no arbitrage and non-redundancy into the proof. Proving closedness is straightforward.